# Both urls provides same json data but flutter can only parse one

Tags: json, flutter

Despite both urls showing the same json data, my code only works with the url "https://5f210aa9daa42f001666535e.mockapi.io/api/products" but the other. Wonder why and been struggling for 3 nights for this:

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
  const String apiUrl =
      "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/book";
  //"https://5f210aa9daa42f001666535e.mockapi.io/api/products";

  final response = await http.get(apiUrl);[enter image description here][1]

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        List<Product> products = (json.decode(response.body) as List)
            .map((data) => Product.fromJson(data))
            .toList();
        // Return list of products
        return products;
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        throw Exception('Failed to load');
      }
```

Comment: since you are not using https, have you taken permission to use unsecured network?

Comment: Hihi, yes added the statement to manifest: <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/> and it works. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think, you try this way. Using package: dio

> https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: Hihi, yes I have tried the dio package. Just that it return null for my localhost url. thanks.

Comment: You should use IP network. ex: 192.168.1.12/api/book. It works for you.